# How redirect time gcc output to a file?

Tags: linux, shell, gcc

I am using the command :

```
time gcc -lm test.c > time.txt
```

to determine the compilation time etc. and then write them to a file.BUt when i use the above command nothing gets printed into the file?

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what shell you use. In bash, `time` is a builtin and cannot be redirected. You have to use a subshell to redirect its standard error:

```
(time gcc -lm test.c ) 2> time.txt
```

Comment: Hmmm, except that you are assuming the `time` used here is the built-in command. Look what happen when you do `(\`which time\` gcc -lm test.c) 2> time.txt`.

Comment: @perror: Others have described what to do with `/usr/bin/time`. I showed what to do with the builtin, as stated in my reply.

Comment: They disappeared... I wrote a summary of both types of answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there are two command `time`. One is a `bash` built-in command and the other one is a usual Unix command.

```
$> type time
time is a shell keyword
$> type `which time`
/usr/bin/time is /usr/bin/time
```

If you want to use the `bash` built-in, you should write as [choroba wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460916/how-redirect-time-gcc-output-to-a-file/16461040#16461040):

```
(time gcc -lm test.c ) 2> time.txt
```

But, if you want to be sure that your script works even if the built-in is not present, you better try to enforce the usage of the **real** `time` command:

```
`which time` -o time.txt gcc -lm test.c
```

For more information about `time` do not hesitate to do `man time`.

Comment: That will only work if you use `/usr/bin/time` on some systems, not if you use the plain `time` builtin.

Comment: I was about to edit my message. It is for the `bash` users only (which has a `time` builtin command that is preferentially used). But you are right.